# SQL SELECT multiple Lines where one line is like, MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, where-clause

Following Setup:

t1

```
ID     Name      Price
1      Miller    50      
2      Smith     10
3      Someone   20
```

t2

```
ID    Item    Price
1     10.1    25
1     10.2    25
2     32.1    10
3     32.1    10
3     11.1    2
3     12.2    3
3     43.2    5
```

What I have to do, is to select all entries from the 2nd Table where one is like 11.1. I'm using this query:

```
SELECT
t1.ID
t1.Name
t2.Item

FROM t1 
JOIN t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t2.item in ('11.1)
```

I should get the following result:

```
ID     Name    Item
3      Someone 31.1
3      Someone 11.1
3      Someone 12.2
3      Someone 43.2
```

but because I do a "where" on a specific item I only get one line. How can I get all the lines from t2 when only 1 line is matching the "11.1"?

Comment: Using MSSQL Server

Comment: this should return 1 row. I couldn't understand What you want?

Comment: Do you need all the items for a particular ID where there is a least one item = '11.1'?

Comment: yes it's a SAP environment, the first table is for the orders. the second one specifies the order listing all the items which were sold. The request is to list all items in an order that contains a specified item

Comment: So you want the details of entire order if the matching item belongs to that order. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

First you need to get the list of IDs of item which is equal to `'11.1'`, then you can get data from table `t2` from the list. You need to join `t1` to get `name`.

```
Select 
   t2.ID, 
   t1.name Name, 
   t2.item Item
from t1 
join t2 
on t1.ID= t2.ID
where t2.ID in (select ID from t2 where item = '11.1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a sub query to get all the elements that shares the same id as the one returned by your condition first.

```
SELECT 
  t2.ID, t2.Item, t1.Name
FROM 
  t1
JOIN
  t2
  ON t2.ID = t1.ID
WHERE t2.ID in (SELECT ID FROM t2 WHERE t2.item in ('11.1'))
```